# fetchedresultscontroller behavior

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a table view that is sorted by a segmented switch.  I want to sort the table by an NSNumericSearch so that I get 1,2,11,22 instead of 1,11,2,22. I'm using Core Data.

If I create multiple records with the 'color' property remaining the same (ie.all 'red'), while varying the length, the sort for length initially is correct (1,2,11,22). If I then switch to another selectedSegmentIndex of the segmented control, such as 'shape' or 'length', I get an erroneous sort order (1,11,2,22) on the same data.

I thought the fetchedResultsController was supposed to recompute the data with a call for the tableView to reload data.

I am not using a predicate.  I have tried setting the cache name to nil with no effect. I have also tried deleteCacheWithName: although it may need to be in a different location.

Some code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController{    
if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return __fetchedResultsController;
} 
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        sortKey = @"color";
        break;
    case 1:
        sortKey = @"length";
        break;
    case 2:
        sortKey = @"smell";
        break;
    case 3:
        sortKey = @"shape";
        break;
    default:
        sortKey = @"color";
        break;
}
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) { return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor2, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sortKey cacheName:@"Master"];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    abort();
}
return __fetchedResultsController;
}
- (IBAction)changeSegment:(id)sender {
switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        sortKey = @"color";
        break;
    case 1:
        sortKey = @"length";
        break;
    case 2:
        sortKey = @"smell";
        break;
    case 3:
        sortKey = @"shape";
        break;
    default:
        sortKey = @"one";
        break;
}
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
//[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];
}
```

Can anyone help me on this behaviour of first time correct, second time incorrect sorting?

Answer (score 2):

From the NSFetchedResultsController documentation:

> **Modifying the Fetch Request**
>   You cannot simply change the fetch request to modify the results. If you want to change the fetch request, you must:
>   If you are using a cache, delete it (using deleteCacheWithName:).
>   Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch request.
>   Change the fetch request.
>   Invoke performFetch:

I can't see where you are doing this. Changing the sort order is equivalent to changing the fetch request.

I also think you have it backwards regarding what is automated with the results controller. It automatically updates your table when the model changes, (if you implement the delegate methods) not the other way round. You may be relying on your property re-loading the fetched results controller when it is accessed from a datasource method, I don't think this is a good idea.

Also, your switch statement on the segmented control action method is irrelevant if you are expecting the FRC to be rebuilt from scratch. I suggest having a separate method that returns your fetch request, which is called from your FRC setup and the segmented control action method, then switching out the request as described in the docs.